# Formatting a string in a datarow

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a question- I am attempting to understand how to format a string as I am cycling through a datarow and all I find when I search is about date/time format. I need to take an account number, say 51100000 and break it apart in the report(ultimate destination is Crystal) so it reads 5 1100 000.
Here is the code I have to populate the datatable: I am specifically looking at Account no.

```
Private Sub write_records()
    For x = 0 To (ds2.Tables("report").Rows.Count - 1)
        mydatarow = mydatatable.NewRow
        mydatarow("Dept no.") = Trim(ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(1))
        mydatarow("Dept Name") = Trim(ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(0))
        mydatarow("Account name") = Trim(ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(3))
        mydatarow("Account no.") = (ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(2))"THIS IS THE LINE I NEED TO FORMAT AS # ##### ###"
        mydatarow("Obudget") = (ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(4))
        mydatarow("Budget") = Trim(ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(5))
        mydatarow("Expenditure") = Trim(ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(6))
        mydatarow("Encumbrance") = Trim(ds2.Tables("report").Rows(x).Item(7))
        mydatarow("Outstanding Balance") = mydatarow("budget") - mydatarow("expenditure") - mydatarow("encumbrance")
        mydatatable.Rows.Add(mydatarow)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

ANSWER(At least for me!!!)

I actually ended up using CR instead with a select case statement- basically length(account) CASE 7:Picture (X XXX XXX) CASE 8:Picture(X XXXX XXX) Thank you!

Comment: [Formatting Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I actually ended up using CR instead with a select case statement- basically  length(account) CASE 7:Picture (X XXX XXX) CASE 8:Picture(X XXXX XXX) Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out:)